# How to pass a value from a method to property procedure in c#?

Tags: c#

Here is my code:

The jewellery class is my main class in which i am inheriting a connection string class.

class Jewellery : Connectionstr
    {

```
    string lmcode;
    public string LM_code/**/Here i want to access the value of the method ReadData i.e displaystring and i want to store this value in the insert query below.**
    {
        get { return lmcode; }
        set { lmcode = value; }

    }


    string mname;
    public string M_Name
    {
        get { return mname; }
        set { mname = value; }
    }

    string desc;
    public string Desc
    {
        get { return desc; }
        set { desc = value; }
    }


    public string ReadData()
    {
        OleDbDataReader dr;
        string jid = string.Empty;
        string displayString = string.Empty;
        String query = "select max(LM_code)from Master_Accounts";
        Datamanager.RunExecuteReader(Constr, query);

        if (dr.Read())
        {
            jid = dr[0].ToString();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(jid))
            {
                jid = "AM0000";
            }
            int len = jid.Length;
            string split = jid.Substring(2, len - 2);
            int num = Convert.ToInt32(split);
            num++;
            displayString = jid.Substring(0, 2) + num.ToString("0000");
            dr.Close();
        }
            **return displayString;** I want to pass this value to the above property procedure above i.e LM_code.

    }

    public void add()
    {

           String query ="insert into Master_Accounts values ('" + LM_code + "','" + M_Name + "'," + "'" + Desc + "')";
           Datamanager.RunExecuteNonQuery(Constr , query);//

     }
```

If possible can u edit this code!

Anticipated thanks by sameer

Comment: It really isn't clear what you're asking. Edit the code to remove the redundant parts (i.e. code that is not pertinent to the question) and then write a clear description of what you are trying to achieve, and the problem you are having.

Comment: Like i said ReadData() is a method it will return a value like say AM0001, i want to pass this value to the property procedure public string LM_code. This LM_code will store the value in the insert query. For detail see my code.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
string lmcode = null;
public string LM_code
{
    get { return lmcode ?? ReadData(); }
    set { lmcode = value; }
}
```

As long as you don't set a `LM_code` it will return the value returned by `ReadData()`. But the problem here is, that you call `ReadData()` all the time. Maybe you want to cache the result - like this:

```
string lmcode = null;
public string LM_code
{
    get { return lmcode ?? ( lmcode = ReadData() ); }
    set { lmcode = value; }
}
```

But that has the drawback, that your value can not be changed during runtime.

**EDIT:**
Your code is completely broken - a try to give you some direction:

```
public string ReadData()
{
    string displayString = string.Empty;
    string query = "select max(LM_code) from Master_Accounts";

    // I'd look for something like ExecuteScalar
    string jid = Datamanager.RunExecuteScalar( Constr, query ).ToString();

    // You don't use the DataReader anymore, since you get your result from your Datamanager

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(jid))
    {
      jid = "AM0000";
    }

    int len = jid.Length;
    string split = jid.Substring(2, len - 2);
    int num = Convert.ToInt32(split);
    num++;
    return displayString = jid.Substring(0, 2) + num.ToString("0000");
 }
```

There are a lot of assumptions - I fear that you have to find out everything else on your own :/ Or you provide some more informations, later.

Comment: @tanascius I think the null coalescing operator (??) was introduced for C# 3.0 or 3.5, the questions use of backing fields suggests that C# 2.0 might be being used.  Hard to say for sure.

Comment: The getter can be rewritten: `if( lmcode == null ) { lmcode = ReadData(); } return lmcode;`

Comment: @amelvin The null coalescing operator (??) was introduced in C#2.0

Comment: Thanks the value is now passing, but still i am having a error in the line

Error 1 
if(dr.Read())//Use of unassigned local variable 'dr'

Comment: @sameer: Yes, you write `OleDbDataReader dr;` but never assign it. You need to write something like `OleDbDataReader dr = ...;`

Comment: but i am reading the value through other class like DataManager.RunExecuterReader(); even if i initialize it fully, it shows an error. Do have any idea of readin the value other than dr.read()?

Comment: @DanDiplo If ?? was introduced in C# 2.0 then there is no problem, I couldn't find a reference to it in my O'Reilly book (Programming C# 4ed - covering C#2.0 and .Net2.0) and the top online search returns Scott Guthrie using it in 2007 in conjunction with lambda expressions.  Note to self: more research needed to make comments on SO!

Comment: @amelvin - I wasn't 100% sure, but I did check and it was introduced along with Nullable types in C# 2.0 (along with Visual Studio 2005). See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/7cz8t42e(v=VS.80).aspx and click Nullable Types link or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173224(v=VS.80).aspx

Comment: @DanDiplo Fair enough, I'm convinced!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to 'pass' data to the property, because LM_Code is backed by the lmcode field. Just assign the value you want to be exposed by LM_Code to the lmcode field. Ie:

```
public string ReadData() 
{ 
    // ... ReadData Logic

    lmcode = displayString;
    return displayString; 
}
```

Consider restructuring this class to prevent consumers from calling your methods in the wrong order. For instance, you will want to be sure that ReadData has been called before you allow add to be executed.